# Why is Mathematica showing a root twice from Reduce or Solve?

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, bugs

If we plot the following, we can see there are seven roots

```
Plot[{x, 3 Pi (1 - Sin[x])}, {x, 0, 22}]
```

We can easily solve for these roots

```
Reduce[x == 3 Pi (1 - Sin[x]), x, Reals]
```

The results are

[image]

Why is Mathematica showing the $3 \pi$ root twice? It is not a double root!

Solve does the same thing.

This appears to be a bug and I thought those sorts of questions were welcome here.

Comment: Showing the multiplicity of a root is what `Solve` normally does, at least for algebraic equations. Like `Solve[x^2 == 0, x]`. Seems unlikely it's a double root, though.

Comment: The behavior is different in "12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019)":`Reduce` doesn't return a `3*Pi` as a double root.  It's possible that this is a bug (or *was* a bug if that point is actually a double root).

Comment: Indeed:  The Taylor expansion of $3\pi(1-\sin(x)) - x$ about $x=3\pi$ is $(3\pi-1)(x-3\pi) -\frac{1}{2}\pi(x-3\pi)^3 +\cdots$, indicating that $3\pi$ is not a double root.  So we might be able to characterize this as a bug, depending on the intention of `Reduce` and when it returns multiple of the same answers.

Comment: @march: Thank you for verifying that!

Comment: In fact, `Series[x - 3  Pi  (1 - Sin[x]), {x, 3  Pi, 3}]` shows that there is only a single root at `x -> 3 Pi`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: That is a nice way to show the issue. Thanks!

Comment: `Reduce` does not care about multiplicity and technically `x==1` is same as `x==1||x==1` and applying `FullSimplify` will get rid off multiple solutions. `Solve` on the other hand care about multiplicity but especially for polynomial equations. For transcendental equations output of `Solve` does not have to be correct regarding multiplicities of solutions.

Comment: @azerbajdzan. Those are very interesting comments. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: This has been reported as a bug.

Comment: As for the questionj of whether this post is appropriate for MSE, I would think the `Reduce` result is sufficiently confusing as to make it a reasonable query. It's not entirely obvious, at least at a glance, that it is "just" a bug.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Thank you for your always helpful comments.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a bug. A subdivision method happens to subdivide very close to a root, and the same root gets found in both branches (due to numerical tolerance). The code was not checking for that, it will in the next version.

Comment: Thank you! ${}{}$

Comment: Where? In `Solve` or `Reduce`?